# Mock reassigning properties in mocked interface

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, jest-mock-extended

I have the following interface which I'm trying to mock:

```js
export interface IEmail {
  from: string;
  body: string;
  to: string;
}
```

This interface is used in a function like:

```js
async function sendEmail(emailData: IEmail): Promise<void> {
  await this.send({
    emailBody: emailData.body,
    emailBodyFrom: emailData.from,
    emailTo: emailData.to,
  });
}

async function send(email) {
  verifyEmail(email)
  emailprovider.send(email)
}
```

I tried mocking the interface with `jest-mock-extended` like this:

```js
it('should send email', async () => {
  const options = mock<IEmail>({
    emailBody: "You got mail",
    from: "marc@meta.com",
    to: "jane.doe@gmail.com",
  });

  mockemailService.send.mockResolvedValueOnce("");
  await emailService.sendEmail(options);
  expect(mockemailService.send).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
    emailBody: 'You got mail',
    emailBodyFrom: 'marc@meta.com',
    emailTo: 'jane.doe@gmail.com',
  });
});
```

Running the test gives the following diff:

```
- emailBody: 'You got mail',
- emailBodyFrom: 'marc@meta.com',
- emailTo: 'jane.doe@gmail.com',
+ emailBody: undefined,
+ emailBodyFrom: undefined,
+ emailTo: undefined,
```

I have debugged and it seems like when I copy the vales from one object to another `emailBody: emailData.body` is causing the value to be undefined.

Is there a better way to create the mock perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it by setting the fields like this instead:

```js
const options = mock<IEmail>({});
options.emailBody = "You got mail"
options.from = "marc@meta.com"
options.to = "jane.doe@gmail.com"
```